# Understanding slice indexing semantics

Tags: go

The answer to the question might be "well that's just how Go is" but I'd like to understand the reasoning behind the following behavior with respect to indexing a slice of a value type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type S struct {
    Data string
}

func main() {
    s := []S{
        {"first"},
        {"second"},
        {"third"},
    }
    
    // # 1
    // This does not modify "s"
    first := s[0]
    first.Data = "something else"
    fmt.Println(s)
    
    // # 2
    // ...but this does?
    s[0].Data = "woah"
    fmt.Println(s)
    
    // # 3
    // ...and this makes sense but feels inconsistent with the previous block
    second := &s[1]
    second.Data = "this makes sense"
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

My question is, why does `#2` update the slice given that `var element S = s[0]` compiles but `var element *S = s[0]` does not compile?

([run this in a playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/ozL0Ma5B3Tv))

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with slices or indexing into slices but with pointers, variable, addresses of variables, type mismatch etc.

Comment: Understood and that’s obviously where the confusion was based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first := s[0]` creates a copy of `s[0]` and assigns to `first`, having a type of `S`.

`s[0].Data = "woah"` is direct assignment, pretty straightforward.

`second := &s[1]` assigns a *pointer* to `s[1]` to `second`, having a type of `*S`. So `second.Data` modifies `s[1].Data` because it's a pointer. Note that Go uses dot for both member access and pointer access (in C this would be the `->` operator).

An equivalent way to write and to understand this would be:

```
var first S
first = s[0]

var second *S
second = &s[1]
```

Comment: Using dot for both member and pointer access in this case I think is what tripped me up. Thanks for the answer this cleared things up

Comment: @kingkupps: those of us used to C and/or C++ here have this problem every now and then. I always thought eliminating the need for `(*p).foo` or `p->foo` would be nice; now I'm less sure about it. :-)

Comment: @torek There *is* one case where discriminating between `.` and `->` would be useful: For iterators that behave like pointers, like `std::vector<something>::iterator`, `p.operator++()` and `p->operator++()` is totally different.

Comment: @iBug: well, yes, but you must mean in C++ since Go doesn't have user defined iterators. (If Go did have them, they would presumably be invoked via `range`. and we would need an explicit `for i, elem := range p` vs `for i, elem := range *p` to invoke, so that the question never comes into play in the first place.)